# What are these dead insects under my kitchen cabinets?

Tags: insect

After removing kitchen cabinets we found these dead insects underneath?  What are they?

There flooring in my kitchen isn’t completely covered.  For example kitchen cabinets have no flooring underneath them.  I notice they exist around these areas perhaps at the edge of the vinyl.  Why so?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell from that dark grainy picture, but blowing it up, they might be dead "pill bugs", also called "roly-poley" bug, "doodle bugs" "wood louse", etc. etc. If so, they are harmless, don't spread diseases, don't destroy anything and are about as benign as you can get. They hide in dark moist places and eat decaying plant matter. So likely someone had garbage rotting under the cabinets at one time and it attracted them, then once it was cleaned out, they died of starvation. To be sure you can take a dead one down to a nursery and see if anyone there can tell you.

Enhanced capture:
[image]